# Cosmos DB and Azure functions Get item .net 5 Asynchrous foreach statement cannot operate on variable of type FeedIterator

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-functions

Im trying to get an item from azure cosmos db in azure functions .net 5.0
but im getting this error because im using async method

```
Feedlterator <rsakeys> Container.GetitemQuerylterator <rsakeys> (QueryDefinition queryDefinition, [string continuation Token = null], [QueryRequestOptions requestOptions = null]) (+ 1 overload) This method creates a query for items under a container in an Azure Cosmos database using a SQL statement with parameterized values.  It returns a Feedlterator.  For more information on preparing SQL statements with parameterized values, please see QueryDefinition.  
Returns: 
An iterator to go through the items.  CS8411: Asynchronous foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'Feediterator <rsakeys>' because 'Feedlterator <rsakeys>' does not contain a suitable public instance or extension definition for 'GetAsyncEnumerator
CS8411: Asynchronous foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'Feediterator <rsakeys>' because 'Feedlterator <rsakeys>' does not contain a suitable public instance or extension definition for 'GetAsyncEnumerator
```

[image]

This is my code, i have not found any good documentation on this error at all, im pretty much lost.

```
namespace projectA
{
    class projectA
    {
        [Function("projectA")]
        async Task<HttpResponseData> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "")] HttpRequestData req,
            FunctionContext context)
        {

            var logger = context.GetLogger("projectA");
            logger.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
            response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");

            /// The Azure Cosmos DB endpoint.
            string EndpointUrl = "https://name.documents.azure.com:443/";

            /// The primary key for the Azure DocumentDB account.
            string PrimaryKey = "primarykey";

            // The Cosmos client instance
            CosmosClient cosmosClient = new CosmosClient(EndpointUrl, PrimaryKey);

            Database database;
            Container container;
            string databaseId = "database1";
            string containerId = "container1";

            var sqlQueryText = "SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.key = '123'";
            Console.WriteLine("Running query: {0}\n", sqlQueryText);
            container = cosmosClient.GetContainer(databaseId, containerId);
            QueryDefinition queryDefinition = new QueryDefinition(sqlQueryText);
 
            List<rsakeys> rsakeyss = new List<rsakeys>();
//In this await foreach i get the error...
                 await foreach (rsakeys RsaKeys in container.GetItemQueryIterator<rsakeys>(queryDefinition))
                {
                    rsakeyss.Add(RsaKeys);
                    Console.WriteLine("\tRead {0}\n", RsaKeys);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

The pattern you would use for a *Feed Iterator* would be

```
while (feedIterator.HasMoreResults)
   foreach (var item in await feedIterator.ReadNextAsync())
       Console.Write(item.Cost);
```

If you wanted to use an awaited foreach (AKA `IAsynEnumerable`), you could roll your own `IAsynEnumerable` to *yield*

```
private static async IAsyncEnumerable<T> SomeMethod<T>(
   Container container,
   QueryDefinition queryDefinition,
   [EnumeratorCancellation] CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
   using var feedIterator = container.GetItemQueryIterator<T>(queryDefinition);
   while (feedIterator.HasMoreResults)
      foreach (var item in await feedIterator
              .ReadNextAsync(cancellationToken)
              .ConfigureAwait(false))
         yield return item;
}
```

**Usage**

```
await foreach(var item in SomeMethod<SomeType>(container, queryDefinition)
   Console.Write(item);
```

---

**Bonus fact**

It's also worth noting that `ReadNextAsync` returns `Task<FeedResponse<T>>`

```
public abstract Task<FeedResponse<T>> ReadNextAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default);
```

`FeedResponse` is inherited from `Response`

```
FeedResponse<T> : Response<IEnumerable<T>>, IEnumerable<T>
```

However, for convenience `Response` has an *implicit operator*, so it can be implicitly converted to its generic Enumerbale type `IEnumerable<T>`

```
public static implicit operator T(Response<T> response)
```

Ergo, both of the following statements are valid

```
using var feedIterator = container.GetItemQueryIterator<Bob>(queryDefinition);

FeedResponse<Bob> bobResponse = await feedIterator.ReadNextAsync()

IEnumerable<Bob> bobs = await feedIterator.ReadNextAsync()
```

**Update From comments**

> After doing using
>
> ```
> var feedIterator = container.GetItemQueryIterator<rsakeys>(queryDefinition); var x =
> await feedIterator.ReadNextAsync();
> Console.WriteLine(x.GetType().ToString());
> ```
>
> I get this console output :
>
> Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.QueryResponse`1[PolarisRSAFunction1NET5.rsakeys]
>
> how do i access the query value?

Calling `ReadNextAsync` would return an `FeedResponse<rsakeys>` from there you can just call [`x.Resource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.response-1.resource?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Response%601.Resource);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=azure-dotnet) to return an `IEnumerable<rsakeys>` or just directly assign it

I.e

```
var response = await feedIterator.ReadNextAsync();
IEnumerable<rsakeys> items = response.Resource;
```

Comment: @ChristopherMartinez  you could call `x.Resource` which would return an `IEnumerable<rsakeys>`